# How to change the event color based on the condition

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I have a kendo schedular and i want to change the color based on the date if event schedule  is  for future date blue color and less than red color and completed as green. and so on.I am doing in the below way but the problem here is sometimes this works $('div.k-event[data-uid="'+eventDetails['uid']+'"]').length if length is >0 otherwise it is not able to set the style when less than 0. Any help on this is highly appreciated.

```
     @(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<BHI.TESQ.Entities.Entities.SchedulerData>()
    .Name("scheduler")
    .Events(e =>
        {
            e.Save("scheduler_save");
            e.Remove("scheduler_remove");
            e.Move("scheduler_move");
            e.Edit("scheduler_edit");
            e.MoveStart("scheduler_moveStart");
            e.ResizeStart("scheduler_ResizeStart");
            e.DataBound("scheduler_dataBound");
        })
    .Group(group => group.Resources("Equipment").Orientation(SchedulerGroupOrientation.Vertical))
    .Resources(resource =>
    {
        resource.Add(m => m.Id)
        .Title("Equipment")
        .Name("Equipment")
        .Multiple(false)
        .DataTextField("Text")
        .DataValueField("Value")
        .DataColorField("Color")
        .DataSource(ds => ds
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetLocations", "Schedule").Data("sendLocations")).Events(e => e.Change("refreshScheduler"))
        );
    })
    .DataSource(d => d
        .Model(m =>
        {
            m.Id(f => f.Id);
            m.Field(f => f.Title).DefaultValue("New Event");
            m.Field(f => f.Start);
            m.Field(f => f.End);
            m.Field(f => f.Description);
            m.Field(f => f.EquipName);
            m.Field(f => f.EquipmentId);
        })
        .Read(read => read.Action("Read", Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()).Data("additionalInfo"))
        .ServerOperation(true)
        )
    .Views(views =>
    {
        views.TimelineWorkWeekView(timeline =>
        {

            timeline.StartTime(new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day, 00, 00, 00).AddDays(-1 * ((int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek)));
            timeline.EndTime(new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day, 00, 00, 00).AddDays(7 - ((int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek)).AddMinutes(-1));

            timeline.EventHeight(25);
            timeline.Title("Work Week View");
            timeline.MajorTick(1500);
        });
        views.TimelineWeekView(timeline =>
        {
            timeline.StartTime(new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day, 00, 00, 00).AddDays(-1 * ((int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek)));
            timeline.EndTime(new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day, 00, 00, 00).AddDays(7 - ((int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek)).AddMinutes(-1));
            timeline.EventHeight(25);
            timeline.Title("Week View");
            timeline.MajorTick(1500);

        });
        views.TimelineMonthView(timeline =>
        {
            timeline.Selected(true);
            timeline.StartTime(new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 01, 00, 00, 00));
            timeline.EndTime(new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, 01, 00, 00, 00).AddMonths(1).AddMinutes(-1));
            timeline.MajorTick(1440);
            timeline.EventHeight(25);
            timeline.Title("Month View");
        });
        views.DayView(dayView =>
        {
            dayView.Title("Day View");
            dayView.StartTime(new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day, 00, 00, 00, 00));

        });
    })

    .Editable(true)
    .Timezone("Etc/UTC")
            //.Timezone("Asia/Calcutta")
    .Height(750)
    .BindTo(Model)
    )

</div>


function scheduler_dataBound(e) {
        var jobTestId = @Convert.ToInt64(Session["JobTestId"]);
        if (e.sender._selectedViewName != "day")
        {
            debugger;
            e.sender._data.forEach(function(eventDetails) {
                if(eventDetails['JobTestId'] != jobTestId)
                {
                    if ($('div.k-event[data-uid="'+eventDetails['uid']+'"]').length != 0)
                    {

                        $('div.k-event[data-uid="'+eventDetails['uid']+'"]')[0].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
                        $('div.k-event[data-uid="'+eventDetails['uid']+'"]')[0].style.color = "white";
                        if (eventDetails['TestStatus'] === 'Completed') {
                            $('div.k-event[data-uid="'+eventDetails['uid']+'"]')[0].style.backgroundColor = "green";
                        }
                        if(eventDetails['TestStatus'] === 'Abandoned')
                        {
                            $('div.k-event[data-uid="'+eventDetails['uid']+'"]')[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
                            $('div.k-event[data-uid="'+eventDetails['uid']+'"]')[0].style.borderColor = "red";
                        }
                        if ((eventDetails['TestStatus'] === 'In Progress' || eventDetails['TestStatus'] === 'Scheduled') && Date.parse(eventDetails['end']) <=  Date.parse(new Date())) {
                            $('div.k-event[data-uid="'+eventDetails['uid']+'"]')[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
                            $('div.k-event[data-uid="'+eventDetails['uid']+'"]')[0].style.borderColor = "red";
                        }
                    }

                }
                else if ($('div.k-event[data-uid="'+eventDetails['uid']+'"]').length != 0)
                    $('div.k-event[data-uid="'+eventDetails['uid']+'"]')[0].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";

            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: always post rendered html than server side code.

Comment: Didnt get you. Could you please explain in detail

Answer (score 1):

According to the Telerik forums, there are two ways to change the color of an event. Via resources or via templates. (more info [enter link description here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/background-color-of-events-in-the-schedule-view)) what I think is easier is to do it via templates, selecting the corresponding template according the date.

UPDATE:

using templates you should have two CSS classes, one for the previous events and other for the future events

```
.EventTemplate("#if(start <new Date()){#"+
"<div class='event-1'></div>"+
"#}else{#"+
"<div class='event-2'></div>"+
"#}#")
```

I made a quick test using the kendo UI dojo, and it works comparing to a specific date, you can watch the demo here [demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/iDUGE)

pd: it doesn't matter if the info comes from the database because the render is done at client side.

Comment: But i will get the data from database...How will I create the templates based on dates. Appreciate if you can provide me with some example